# JMeter Load Test: Disable/remove duplicate page and -0 -1 in result tree

Tags: jmeter

I export the jmx script from blazemeter chrome plugin.

Question 1:
My load test accurate or not if I disable or remove the duplicate url and .php or .json (it something like themes or scriptpage) because the page that I want to test actually without the extension.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/85IJs.png

Question 2:
What is the meaning of number -0 , -1 ,... in result tree .... as below pic?

https://i.stack.imgur.com/sEajc.png

Answer (score 0):

1. If you want to exclude some specific URLs or patterns while recording, then use the **Requests Filtering** tab at the [HTTP(S) Test Script Recorder](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#HTTP(S)_Test_Script_Recorder)

[image]

Please check this Guide for further reference: [Excluding Domains from the Load Test](https://guide.blazemeter.com/hc/en-us/articles/206732519-Excluding-Domains-from-the-Load-Test).

2. This is basically the **index** of your sub-samplers. This SubResult Naming Policy is introduced from the JMeter version 5.0.

Before **version 5.0**, when your HTTP Sampler contained sub results, they would have their own names. In 5.0, a new custom naming policy was introduced for sub-samplers.

> sub-result name = parent sampler name + index

Check this [BUG 62550](https://bz.apache.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=62550) for further reference.